# NestJS File Upload in chunks

Tags: file, upload, nestjs, multer, chunks

Does anyone know how to upload a single file in chunks using NestJS?

I cannot find any working example related to that online.

Here's my current implementation

```js
@Post()
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
          const dir = path.join(ENV.MNT);
          cb(null, dir);
        },
        filename: editFileName,
      }),
      fileFilter: fileFilter,
    }),
  )
  uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
    console.log(file);

    return true;
  }
```

file is undefined (I suppose because the file has not yet been fully received, so no metadata, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I have working example in my servers, it is similar to yours. Probably "storage: diskStorage" property in your options causes error.

I upload 350mb data without any problem, but it takes some time depends on your connection speed. I didn't test much bigger files, but i think it should work. The point is, uploadFile function runs after your upload finishes. You should see console.log after all upload finished.

```
@Post()
@UseInterceptors(
  FileInterceptor('file', {
    dest: './storage/uploads'
  }),
)
uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
    console.log(file);
    return file;
}
```